# "ГарантироваНо" или "гарантироваННо"?

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте. Ежедневно езжу домой мимо автозаправочной станции. У них вывеска "КАЧЕСТВО ГАРАНТИРОВАНО". Но мне почему-то кажется, что ГАРАНТИРОВАНО должно писаться через двойную НН. Подскажите, как все-таки правильно пишется это словосочетание? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: **качество гарантировано (краткое причастие)**. Форма "гарантированно" является **наречием** и относится к глаголу или прилагательному:

1)  Право на отдых **гарантировано** Конституцией. В противном случае им **не гарантировано** ничего.

2) Работники наших заготовительных предприятий **гарантированно** имеют все льготы. Эта продукция **гарантированно** безопасна для детей.

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от того, что имел в виду автор. Если ** гарантировано** - то есть я гарантирую, нами гарантировано - причастие, то пишем одну Н. Если **качество (каково? гарантированно**) - краткое прилагательное, пишем столько Н, сколько в полной форме, то есть две. Поскольку у слова здесь нет никаких зависимых слов, указывающих точно на причастие, можно написать две. Но в таком небольшом контексте и одна Н не ошибка, если... см. начало.

Answer (score 0):

Я уже ответил на этот вопрос здесь [Гарантированно / гарантировано](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8925/%d0%93%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be/425053#425053)

Не важно, что имел в виду автор, читатель в голову к нему не залезет - это его авторское дело писать так, чтобы быть понятым однозначно.  Вам правильно кажется, *гарантированно* должно писать через два н:  никаких признаков причастия в тексте нет, а каноничный орфографический словарь ИЯ АН СССР 1957 года говорит однозначно - **гарантированный**.

Качество каково? гарантированно.
"гарантированно" это краткое прилагательное так как отвечает на вопрос прилагательного и обозначает признак имени существительного *качество*.

Есть правило: слова на *-ованный, -ёванный, -еванный* — отглагольные прилагательные и всегда пишутся с двумя Н: прессованный, корчеванный, иллюстрированный, маринованный, гарантированный(**!**). А как известно, в кратких прилагательных пишется столько же н, сколько и в полных.

Answer (score 0):

Как раз важно, что имел в виду автор, ибо вы можете подменить в своих рассуждениях причастие на прилагаетльное, не имея на то ровно никаких оснований. 
В случае с причастием нет абсолютно никаких правил, обязывающих автора это особо указывать, – это выдумка чистой воды.
И причастие пишется именно с одной "н", а никак не с двумя.

Comment: Семантика словосочетания изменится, если поменять одно на другое? Если да, то как, если нет, почему не установить единое правило?

Answer (score 0):

Одна «н». *«Гарантировано»* — это причастие.

Удивляет мнение авторов ответов, что *«гарантирован(н)о»* может быть прилагательным. Фраза *«качество гарантировано»* полностью аналогична (в т. ч. по смыслу) словосочетанию *«слово дано»*. В первом случае нам дают гарантию, во втором — слово. Только во втором случае почему-то никто не засомневается в правописании...