# Гарантированно / гарантировано

Tags: орфография, суффиксы, удвоенные-буквы

Покупатель гарантированно получает подарок. — Здесь понятно: краткое прилагательное, значит, удвоенное н.

Качество гарантировано. — Здесь краткое причастие, значит, одно н.

А вот почему в предложении "Вы даёте информацию, неразглашение которой гарантированно" в слове "гарантированно" нужно писать две н, непонятно. Почему в последнем предложении "гарантированно" с удвоенным н?

Comment: Простите, Marina-ja, нужно кое-что уточнить. В предложении "Покупатель гарантированно получает подарок" слово гарантированно не краткое прилагательное, а наречие.

Comment: Да, вы правы, я ошиблась при определении части речи.

Answer (score 5):

Скорее всего, слово "гарантирова(Н,НН)о употреблено здесь в значении "то, что гарантировали", поэтому писать его надо с одной Н, это краткое причастие:  "неразглашение гарантировано".
  Впрочем, в выражении "неразглашение гарантированно" слово "гарантированно" может быть употреблено в значении "несомненно", тогда оно является кратким  прилагательным, отвечает на вопрос КАКОВО? и пишется с двумя Н. Ср.: Вы даёте информацию с гарантированным (=несомненным)неразглашением её.
Но я думаю, что первый вариант более правильный.

Answer (score 2):

Предложение слишком внезапно заканчивается, поэтому нельзя однозначно сказать, причастие это или наречие к прилагательному. Смысл мог бы быть таким: "... гарантировано нашей супер-пупер системой хранения". В этом случае это причастие, и поэтому одна "н". Но ведь замысел мог бы быть и таким: "... гарантированно приведёт к тому, что нас лишат лицензии" ("гарантированно" здесь в смысле "обязательно"). Второй вариант смысла получился таким надуманным, поскольку я не смог придумать более-менее реального смысла, который можно было бы подразумевать, заканчивая предложение именно наречием. Так что, скорее всего, написание с удвоенной "н" - это просто ошибка.

Comment: Нормально оно заканчиваеется. "Покупатель получает подарок" - нормально? Неужели добавление "гарантировано"  что-то в этом меняет. 
Другое дело, что само по себе "гарантировано" тут как из другого мира. Можно бы и по-русски сказать. "Наверняка", к примеру. 

Рассуждения насчет смысла и системы хранения - за уши притянутые. Не надо выдумавать того, чего нет во фразе. Эдак любую фразу можно продолжить, изменив до неузнаваемости.

Предыдущий ответ считаю исчерпывающим, ваш - только путает.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Хотя и жаль, что вы не оценили мой ответ по достоинству.

Comment: Почему ж "не оценил"? Как раз очень даже.

Comment: Тогда ещё раз спасибо за ваше мнение.

Comment: Да еще раз пожалуйста. Захотите ещё пофлудить - к вашим услугам.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю в зависимости от смысла. Если "гарантировано" в смысле кем-то, тогда -н-, если "гарантированно" в смысле как, тогда двойное -НН-

Answer (score 0):

Да ну бросьте, нашли что обсуждать - этот случай как раз из тех, что абсолютно прозрачны. Не должно быть никаких "в зависимости от смысла", подразумевать, логадываться... Язык это система передачи информации - **СИСТЕМА**, понимаете? Не превращайте его в магию.
Как выше пишет behemothus: "Не надо выдумавать того, чего нет во фразе. Эдак любую фразу можно продолжить, изменив до неузнаваемости."
Не надо думать за кого-то - это авторское дело писать так, чтобы быть понятым однозначно.

К делу.
Текст не содержит **никаких** признаков причастия, зато содержит все признаки имени прилагательного.
"Вы даёте информацию, неразглашение которой гарантированно"
**В данном тексте**, это наше спорное "гарантированно" зависит от имени существительного "неразглашение": неразглашение каково? гарантированно - значит "гарантированно" это краткое прилагательное так как отвечает на вопрос прилагательного и обозначает признак имени существительного.
Смотрим в каноничном орфографическом словаре 1957 года ИЯ АН СССР - гарантированный. Как известно, в кратких прилагательных пишется столько же н, сколько и в полных.
Вопрос решён - правильное написание "гарантированно"!

Но не всегда же есть словарь под рукой. На этот случай есть правило: слова на *-ованный, -ёванный, -еванный* — отглагольные прилагательные и всегда пишутся с двумя Н: прессованный, корчеванный, иллюстрированный, маринованный, гарантированный(**!**).
Не следует путать с ними **прилагательные** типа жёваный, клёваный, кованый, у которых сочетания *ов, ёв* входят в состав корня.

В то же время:
    *кова**н**ый* сапог – нет приставки, нет зависимых слов, образовано от глагола несовершенного вида - отглагольное прилагательное;
    *окова**нн**ая* дверь – имеет приставку, образовано от глагола совершенного вида - причастие;
    *кова**нн**ый* в кузнице лемех – есть зависимое слово "в кузнице" - причастие.